# How to use static route to connect 2 routers with another router?

Tags: networking, router, routing, lan

I have 1 router (R1) connected to the internet which has `LAN IP 192.168.0.1` and `Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0`

I have another router (R2) which is connected from 1 LAN port of R1 to the Internet port of R2. This router has `LAN IP 192.168.1.1` and `Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0` and `WAN IP: 192.168.0.110 (static)`

I also have a third router (R3) which has the same kind of connection as `R1 <-> R2`. This router has `LAN IP 192.168.2.1` and `Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0` and `WAN IP: 192.168.0.120 (static)`

The 3 routers are placed in 3 houses (next to each other) and I can't make any more physical connection (more cables router from one to another)

[image: Routing Diagram]

My goal is to get the LAN/Wireless network of R2 to talk to the LAN/Wireless network of R3 without using internet, and without any access to the LAN/Wireless network of R1. I also want to keep access to each router's web interface. From what I've read online, static routing is what I need.

**What am I supposed to enter in `Destination IP, Subnet Mask, Gateway` in the Static Routing Table of the 3 routers so that I can make this connection possible ?**

This is the Web Interface of R2:
[image: R2 Web UI]

This is the Web Interface of R1/R3:
[image: R1/R3 Web UI]

I'm kind of a beginner at networking so I don't know what a "subnet" is and how to properly set the connection(s).

Comment: Can you tell us the WAN IP of R2 and R3?  I can provide the static routes with this information.

Comment: This is a bit more complex than static routes. Assuming these are basic soho routers they are also doing NAT. R2 and R3 networks will not communicate with each other when NAT is in play. Your R1 network is also not protected by anything - it is completely exposed. In fact your R2 and R3 networks are more protected from R1 and each other than the other way around. There is a technical solution to this if someone is willing to teach and describe in detail how to do everything. The better question is, should you?

Comment: @TDurden I've added the required information

Comment: @Appleoddity what do you mean by "your R1 network is also not protected by anything" ? Without considering R2 and R3, wouldn't that be a regular consumer network that almost everyone has ? Also, I can disable NAT on R2, would that help ?

Comment: Your goal is “no access to the LAN/Wireless network of R1.” How do you intend to do that when all traffic has to traverse the R1 network? Yes, it is possible. Right now, R1 is the least protected network in the entire setup you have.

Answer (score 1):

Web Interface of R2:

Network destination: 192.168.2.1
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Default gateway: 192.168.0.1 (based on your print you'll have to go to the R1 before going to R2)
Interface: the interface where the cable to R1 is plugged.
Description: (it's up to you, mate!)

Web Interface of R1/R3:

Click on add new.
Destination IP address: 192.168.2.1
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Default gateway: 192.168.2.1
Interface: the interface where the cable to R3 is plugged.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find access point mode on your R2 and R3 router, enable it. That would make the routers communicate with each other, that is if you don't mind all devices being in the 192.168.0.x IP addresses